# How to determine the cgroup of a device and give it to a lxc container

Tags: linux, device-driver, lxc, cgroups

I'm new to lxc and cgroups. I'm trying to isolate an app, and building it's container with LXC.

So far I'm able to give it some resources such as `/dev/tty0` or `/dev/fb0`. That's fine, however I'm struggling to find how the number of the `/proc/*/` corresponding is found:

```
lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c 4:0 rwm
lxc.mount.entry = /dev/tty0 dev/tty0 none bind,optional,create=file

lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c 4:5 rwm
lxc.mount.entry = /dev/tty5 dev/tty5 none bind,optional,create=file

lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c 29:0 rwm
lxc.mount.entry = /dev/fb0 dev/fb0 none bind,optional,create=file
```

It seems that for instance for `fb0` the `29` comes from `/proc/29` and the `0` comes from `fb0`. How can I determine for a given resources what are the number it shall be associated to?

Why is tty associated with 4 and frame buffer to 29?

```
cat /proc/devices
```

Gives part of the answer, however what about `/dev/input/*`? `sdaX`? Or `/dev/mmcblk0X`?

What is the way to know the cgroup belonging to a given resource? Any documentation or guides would be very welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that this is actually simpler than it seems.

If you want to share /dev/tty0 just look for minor and major numbers :

```
# ls -l /dev/tty5
crw--w---- 1 root tty 4, 5 Jan  1 01:37 /dev/tty5
```

If you want to share char device /dev/tty5 then you want to allow :

```
lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c 4:5 rwm
lxc.mount.entry = /dev/tty5 dev/tty5 none bind,optional,create=file
```

`c` comes from char, 4 is the major number and `5` the minor number

If you want to share /dev/sda1 :

```
# ls -l /dev/sda1
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 1 Jan  1 01:37 /dev/sda1
```

then add :

```
lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = b 8:1 rwm
```

where `b` comes for block device, `8` major number `1` minor number.